# Add two string in jQuery

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller

I am trying to add two string and pass as one throught ajax to controller:

```
var hours = $('#hours').val();
var mintues = $('#minutes').val();




   var toDbViewModel = {
                           ClientId: clientId,
                           ProjectId: projectId,
                           TaskId: taskId,
                           Description: description,
                           Duration: hours + minutes
                       }
```

When json reach the controller value of duration ( let say hours = 3):

```
"3[ojbect HTMLInputElement]"
```

Whenever hour is always good but minutes are "[ojbect HTMLInputElement]"

What do I do wrong?

--EDIT--

```
<input id="hours" type="number" class="form-control" style="width: 70px" placeholder="h" />
 <input id="minutes" type="number" class="form-control" style="width: 70px" placeholder="m" />
```

Comment: what input type is your `#minutes`

Comment: take a look up, edited

Comment: Can we see the rest of the inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> concatenate first and than pass to your JSON

If you see this  [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/chky98b0/) , its working properly

```
 var hours = $('#hours').val();
var mintues = $('#minutes').val();

var hours_min=hours +"."+mintues ;


   var toDbViewModel = {
                           ClientId: clientId,
                           ProjectId: projectId,
                           TaskId: taskId,
                           Description: description,
                           Duration: hours_min
                       }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change jquery object value name it is spilling mistake for the **minutes**.

Change line as per below your code will work.

```
        var hours = $('#hours').val();
        var mintues = $('#minutes').val();
        var toDbViewModel = {
            ClientId: "1",
            ProjectId: "1",
            TaskId: "1",
            Description: "1",
            Duration: hours + mintues
        }
```

You were used minutes and none of any jquery element for this name so it was returned html object which is same name.

```
<input id="minutes" type="number" class="form-control" style="width: 70px"
placeholder="m" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In JSON only double quotes are valid.

From the documentation (http://json.org/):

> A value can be a string in double quotes, or a number, or true or
>   false or null, or an object or an array. These structures can be
>   nested. In other words, no strings in single quotes.

So, try to define your json like this:

```
var toDbViewModel = {
                           "ClientId": clientId,
                           "ProjectId": projectId,
                           "TaskId": taskId,
                           "Description": description,
                           "Duration": hours + minutes
                       }
```

Comment: still the same issue ;(